# Remove error when running ffmpeg in Windows script to shrink MP3 file

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

I use a script to downsize audiobook files.
The original audiobook file was concatenated from multiple MP3 files into one MP3 file.
The script (in Windows) relies on ffmpeg (version git-2020-06-26-7447045) and contains

```
FOR %%A IN (dir *.mp3) DO ffmpeg -i "%%A" -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 8 "_%%A"
```

However, this error message appears:

> deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
> [mp3 @ 000001f026d56400] Frame rate very high for a muxer not efficiently supporting it.
> Please consider specifying a lower framerate, a different muxer or -vsync 2

How do I modify the script for greater efficiency and remove that error message?

Comment: See [the answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/1344802/flac-to-mp3-with-ffmpeg-leads-to-warning-frame-rate-very-high-for-a-muxer-not-e).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) album art instead of re-encoding it:

```
FOR %%A IN (dir *.mp3) DO ffmpeg -i "%%A" -c:v copy -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 8 "_%%A"
```

Other, unrelated suggestions:

- Add `-ac 1` if you want to make the outputs mono to save space (assuming the inputs are stereo).
- Consider using Opus (`-c:a libopus`) instead of MP3 if you want to use a modern, very efficient encoder for lower bitrates.

Comment: [ FOR %%A IN (dir *.mp3) DO ffmpeg -i "%%A" -vn -c:a libopus -b:a 48000 "_%%A" ] resulted in phasey distorted .OGG audio, with only about a 1/8 reduction in size. However, your stream copy command worked well. Converting to mono reduced the brightness & spaciousness of the audio, but did reduce the file size. Thank you for the solution!